# Create link to a document using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell

Just wondering if you could help, I am looking to create a link to a file in a document library, essentially replicating this functionality:

[image: New Link]

I was hoping it would be simple to do this using PnP PowerShell I have tried the using the **Add-PnPFile** however this always expects a stream when running the command below.

> Add-PnPFile -FileName "Something.url" -Folder "Folder 1"

Appreciate any help or advice that can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A demo for your reference:

```
$stream = [IO.MemoryStream]::new([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("[InternetShortcut]URL=https://www.bing.com"))


Add-PnPFile -FileName "Bing.url" -Folder "Shared Documents" -Stream $stream -Values @{_ShortcutUrl="https://www.bing.com"}
```